# What is the difference between vrmlloader.js and vrmloader.js?

Tags: javascript, vrml

I have looked online and could not find a proper post explaining what the difference of application is between the vrmlloader.js and vrmloader.js. Does anyone mind explaining or rederecting me to a page where I can read/learn about the difference between the two? Thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide some code examples?

Comment: There are these 2 project where vrml loader is used for 1 and vrm loader for the other one, but I would not know whichone to use for the situation, for example does the vrm loader allow you to load in files with armatures while the other one does not? VRML loader example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_vrml.html VRM loader example threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_vrm.html , I hope this suffices